# Moving CloudWatch logs to S3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have some logs in CloudWatch and everyday, I keep getting new logs. Now, I want to store today's and yesterday's logs in Cloud Watch itself but logs that are 2 days older have to be moved to S3.

I have tried using the CLI by following the below link :

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/create-export-task.html
```

In this link, two options have been mentioned : **--from** and **--to**

```
--from option only exports the logs after that time.
--to option does not export the logs after that time.
```

By using these, I can achieve my requirement but, I have to type in the command everyday as the --from and --to option values change.

So, instead of typing the command daily, is there an alternative option which could do the job daily without me interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Lambda function to do this for you and set it up to run on cron schedule. Lambda will definitely help you automate this process.

Lambda event source will be then **CloudWatch Events - Schedule**.

See [Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) in AWS docs.